# FastAPI behind Nginx reverse proxy, significantly worse performance than accessing the api directly

Tags: python, nginx, fastapi

I am trying to use FastAPI to deploy multiple copies of LLM inferencing on different machines. For load balancing and reverse proxy I decided to use Nginx, but performance of individual servers drastically decreases when I send requests through the nginx when compared to sending them directly (from around 100 rps to 25).

Nginx and worker are located on different servers on aws (I tested it on different cloud providers and it still the same, so it is not a problem). Nginx is launched in docker container, with `--network host` parameter.

Here is my nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000000;
}
http {
    upstream backend {
        server server_ip1:8000;
        server server_ip2:8000;
        
        keepalive 16;
    }
    
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend/;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
}
```

For model serving I use vllm, which uses basic FastAPI application.
Is it a problem with nginx or FastAPI server?

Edit.
The command used to run worker: `uvicorn.run(app, host=args.host, port=args.port, log_level="debug", timeout_keep_alive=TIMEOUT_KEEP_ALIVE)`
Also there is no specific configs, just FastAPI defaults.

Comment: Please add the command and server/worker configs you are using .i.e uvicorn parameters etc. for both before and after nginx implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The problem was that I was using locust for measuring rps, and it used the same connection between request, but when I was going through nginx it created new connection for each request.
To 'fix' this, here is a nginx config I used:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000000;
}
http {
    upstream backend {
        server server_ip1:8000;
        server server_ip2:8000;
        
        keepalive 2000;
    }
    
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend/;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
    }
}
```

I still don't understand why terminating connection between requests tanks the performance so much.